# Change a Category Name without affecting the existing products within that category

Tags: category, magento2.2

I just realized that I incorrectly named a sub category and its url on a Magento 2.2.7 site. This category currently has approximately 150 products in it. Can I just simply edit the Category Name or will that affect the existing products under that category?

Answer (score 1):

not affect anywhere you can just edit category name or change url
and run below command

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Answer (score 0):

-> if you change category name using the code please use below code.
   if you change category name using this code not affect in the existing product.
   And yes store id requires in below code so don't forget to set store id.

```
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
// require __DIR__ . '../../csv/Customer.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$category = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load(3);
$d["entity_id"] = "3";
$d["is_active"] = "1";

$d["name"] = "TESTA-2_ENG";

// $d["url_key"] = "testa-1-eng";
$d["store_id"] = "0";
$category->setData($d);
$category->save();
$categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface')->save($category);
```

After changing category name you need to reindex require.